# AUTH0 In production after log in it sends me to https://localhost/callback and not to my website

Tags: node.js, auth0

I have created a proyect in Nodejs using Auth0. Everything works perfectly in my local machine using https://localhost

When I upload to my linux machine and go to https://portal.mywebsite.com it redirects me to Auth0 login page and after using the proper credentials it sends me to https://localhost/callbacks instead to https://portal.mywebsite.com/callbacks and is not working

Here is my configuration:

[image]

The BASE_URL in my .env is the following https://portal.myweb.com/
I had also tried with https://localhost and it is not working

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was uploading to the server an older version of the .env with the BASE_URL = https://localhost instead of https://portal.myweb.com/